# Rewriting a Django application from ground-up, is it possible to migrate user model?

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a web app that I developed while learning back-end web development. I deployed it a while back and ended up getting some real users registered. Unfortunately, I wrote some smelly code and it is becoming very difficult to implement any new features without having to refactor large portions of the code base, so I am planning to rewrite the back-end.

The main issue I'm facing is whether there is a way to migrate the CustomUser model I've created to a new PostgreSQL database. Is this possible by simply recreating the same model in the new backend, then doing a pg_dump and restore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have too many users, and you are using an identical model, it might be easiest to use the [dumpdata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-dumpdata) management command on your old system, and use the resulting fixture to [loaddata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-loaddata) on your new system.

Comment: good idea, also your new user model does not need to be identical, you can write some script that transforms the dumped JSON into the new user model structure.